# Can not transfer an image of an icon from a JLabel to another

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, icons

I want to drag an image from an icon on a jlabel to drop it on another icon on a second jlabel. The problem is that some implementations of drag and drop Transferhandler methods do not seem to be called and I can not retrieve the image from the first jlabel's icon. Hope you will find the issue in my code.

```
class dndHandler extends TransferHandler implements Transferable {

    private final DataFlavor flavors[] = { DataFlavor.imageFlavor };

    private Image image;

        @Override
        public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
            System.out.println("test"); // Does not work
            return TransferHandler.COPY;
        }

        @Override
        public Transferable createTransferable(JComponent comp) {
            System.out.println("test"); // Does not work
             image = null;
             image = (Image)((ImageIcon) (((JLabel)comp).getIcon())).getImage(); //We transfer image //image stays null
             return this;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canImport(JComponent comp, DataFlavor flavor[]) {
            if (!(comp instanceof JLabel)) {
                return false;
            }
            System.out.println("test"); //It works here
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean importData(JComponent comp, Transferable t) {
            if (comp instanceof JLabel) {

                    System.out.println(((JLabel)comp).getName()); //It works but the image is null
                    ((JLabel)comp).setIcon(new ImageIcon(image)); //The label stays empty
                    return true;
            } 
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) {
            if (isDataFlavorSupported(flavor)) {
                return image;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
            return flavors;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
            return flavors[0].equals(flavor);
        }

    }

    MouseListener specialListener = new SpecialDragMouseAdapter();

    class SpecialDragMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
            JComponent comp = (JComponent)evt.getSource();
            TransferHandler th = comp.getTransferHandler();

            // Start the drag operation
            th.exportAsDrag(comp, evt, TransferHandler.COPY);
        }

    }

public class PrincipalFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    TransferHandler dropHandler = new dndHandler();

    public PrincipalFrame()
    {
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel();

        label1.setName("label "+i+"-"+j);
        label1.setSize(50,50);
        label1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(java.awt.Color.black));
        label1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("put a file path on your computer"))
        label1.addMouseListener(specialListener);
        label1.setTransferHandler(dropHandler);

        label2.setName("label "+i+"-"+j);
        label2.setSize(50,50);
        label2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(java.awt.Color.black));
        label2.addMouseListener(specialListener);
        label2.setTransferHandler(dropHandler);
  }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    /*
     * Create and display the form
     */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            javax.swing.JFrame principalFrame = new PrincipalFrame();
            //Size of the window
            Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            principalFrame.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width,
                                   Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height-40);
            //Center the window
            principalFrame.setLocation(0,0);
            principalFrame.setVisible(true); 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I be waiting for someone to answer this, this will add something to my knowledge, but the kind of code you had posted doesn't appears to me a good SSCCE. Please do post a good [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @GagandeepBali  There is 'Good SSCCE, bad SSCCE & not an SSCCE'.  That code fits the last category.  To the OP.  To make an SSCCE, you'll need to do various things, including sourcing some images 1) from the JRE 2) hot-linked, or 3) generated at run-time.

Comment: *"Now its right."*  Now **read** the linked document.

Comment: @MHD please how to compile this code

Comment: @mKorbel Now it is possible (sorry for the inconvenience).

Comment: I wanted to precise that we could actually use "TransferHandler dropHandler = new Transferhandler("icon");" but I needed to extend the Transferhandler class to be able to save the icon image in a specific object.

Comment: Does the drag itself start? Is the little drag-icon attached to your cursor when you try it?

Comment: @AaronDigulla Yes everything works but at the drop step there is no image dropped.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I'm only volunteer,

one error

[image]

second error

[image]

third error

[image]

.

then please read tutorial about [Drag and Drop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html), example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1780__Drag-Drop.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Well I have already seen these examples (and many others) but without success (no image is dropped at the end) but it worked for me when I used directly Transferhandler("icon"). Now I want to make it with an extension of Transferhandler to implement an algorithm during image drop to save it somewhere.

Comment: You have to import some classes.

Comment: this is result after Java imports, captured from Netbeans IDE, similair from Eclipse

Comment: Please use the swing gui editor to create a frame with two labels and put the rest of the code (handler, etc.) and try it ;).

Comment: simple I don't see any reason to do so, tell my why :-)

Comment: To avoid these errors. Make only one frame in which you have 2 labels.